# java - Connecting and Disconnecting from networks on windows/linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, networking

I've been searching for an answer to this question but it seems there have only been answers regarding implementing it on Android.

What I'm trying to do is have a Java program that, after meeting certain conditions, will disconnect the home network and then subsequently connect to a different network. Keep in mind, the primary application of this software will be on Windows and Linux systems.

Any tips would be a massive help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Runtime exec to use os commands via Java.

This is OS depend so you need to check which command to use, for example (assuming it is a wireless network):

```
// Windows
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netsh wlan disconnect");
// Linux
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ifconfig wlan0 down");
```

[Technet docs for netsh wlan connect](https://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dd744890(v=ws.10).aspx#bkmk_wlanConn).